# Charged particle in uniform $\vec{B}$ and $\vec{E}$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, charge

> A particle of mass $10^{-26}\ kg$ and charge $1.6\times 10^{-19}\ C$ traveling with a velocity of $1.28\times 10^{6}\ m/s$ in the $+x$ direction enter a region in which  a uniform electric field $E$ and a uniform magnetic field  $B$ are present such that $E_x=E_y=0$ and $E_z=-102.4\ kV/m$ and $B_x=B_z=0$ and $B_y=8\times 10^{-2}\ Wb/m^2$. The particle enters this region at the origin at time $t=0$ find $x-$ coordinate of the particle at $t=5\times 10^{-6}\ s$.

My attempt:

There is no velocity and force in $y$- direction, hence we consider particle's velocity at any time $t$ equals to $u_x\hat{i}+u_z\hat{k}$. By Lorentz force$$\vec{F}=q\bigg(-\vec{E}\hat{k}+(u_x\hat{i}+u_z\hat{k})\times\vec{B}\hat{j}\bigg)$$ $$\implies\vec{F_x}=-q{u_z}B\ ,\ \vec{F_z}=q(u_xB-E)$$So, $a_x=-\dfrac{qu_zB}{m}$ and $a_z=\dfrac{q}{m}(u_xB-E)$.

Now for $u_z$, initial velocity in $z$ direction was zero$\implies a_z\cdot t=u_z\implies u_z=t\cdot\dfrac{q}{m}(u_xB-E)$, putting this in $a_x$ we have $$a_x=-\dfrac{q^2B\cdot t}{m^2}\cdot(u_xB-E)\tag{1}\\u_x\dfrac{du_x}{dx}=-\dfrac{q^2B\cdot t}{m^2}\cdot(u_xB-E)\\\int\dfrac{u_x}{(u_xB-E)}\cdot du_x=-\int\dfrac{q^2Bt}{m^2}\cdot dx$$

We know initial velocity in $+x$ direction, for finial velocity from $(1)$$$\dfrac{du_x}{dt}=-\dfrac{q^2B\cdot t}{m^2}\cdot(u_xB-E)\\ \int_{u_{i}} ^{u_f}\dfrac{1}{(u_xB-E)}\cdot du_x=-\dfrac{q^2B}{m^2}\int_{0} ^{t} t\cdot dt$$This provides us the $u_{f}$, final velocity in $x$ direction. But I think I'm diverging away from this problem, these integrals includes $\log_{e}$ stuff and this problem has pretty result as $\frac{32}{5}$.

Now how to carry it further, please help.

Comment: $\implies a_z\cdot t=u_z$ this is wrong, as $u_z = \int a_z dt$. Try some google search on how to solve coupled differential equations (one of the way is to differentiate any of the two equations and substitute. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/508989/how-to-solve-the-coupled-differential-equations

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi any other way to solve, easier than this.

Comment: Please note that this site is not a place to obtain solutions to worked problems. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/25301) and [this Meta post for "check my work problems"](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/25301).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to solve the two coupled differential equations
$a_x=-\dfrac{qu_zB}{m}$ and
$a_z=\dfrac{q}{m}(u_xB-E)$

Hint: Differentiate any of them(say, the second one) and substitute $a_x$ from the first equation, so that you have a second order differential equation in only $z$. Notice that this is an equation of S.H.M., which might be familiar to you.

Comment: as we need x stuff so is it advisable to make those equations for x rather than for z?

Comment: You can differentiate the first one as well. By the way, then the equation in $x$ will not be that of S.H.M. You can always solve anyone and get the other variable by back-substituting.

Comment: I got $x=\frac{Em}{qB^2}\cdot\sin(\omega t)$ then applied angle approximation for $\sin$ gives $x=\frac{E}{B}\cdot t $,  how? Did Imissed something, if not then why do they gave us with values of $u_i$?

Comment: You cannot use angle approximations. You have to put the initial values to the general solution. I think, at first you should properly learns how to solve these differential equations, and put initial values. Note that the general solution involves both sine and cosine functions